# what is wrong with this solution for Candy I (spoj)

Tags: c++

here is the ideone link for the source code for you to test your edits: https://ideone.com/3yDtFb
here is the link for the problem:http://www.spoj.com/problems/CANDY/
it appears to give me WA on spoj despite passing given test cases with correct format,here's the code.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
long long int i,n,each,min;
cin>>n;
while(n!=-1)
{
    long long int a[n],sum=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>a[i];
        sum+=a[i];
    }
    if(sum%n!=0)
        cout<<-1;
    else
    {
        each=sum/n;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(a[i]>each)
                min=(a[i]-each);
        }
        cout<<min<<endl;
    }
    cin>>n;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well technically it's not a C++ program because C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).

Comment: I apologize for my Ignorance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You lost `min=0` , `min+=` and `cout<<-1<<endl`

```
    min=0;
    each=sum/n;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]>each)
            min+=(a[i]-each);
    }
    cout<<min<<endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Even I had the same query. Around half an hour later and going through EVERY iteration, it clicked : variables 'sum' and 'min' were getting carried on to the next test case. 
Thus, initialize them in the outer 'while' scope.